# How is the "out of phase" nature of imaginary part of an oscillator related to the dissipation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, condensed-matter

Ever since I was an undergrad learning about damped harmonic oscillators, we learned that the imaginary part of the response function means a 90 degree out of phase response, as well as a non-reversible, dissipation process. But it is never intuitive to me why is "phase differ by 90 degrees" results in "non-reversible and dissipation". Similar thing applies to the complex susceptibility $\chi'(\omega)+\chi''(\omega)$ of magnets and conductors.

I know textbooks often derive the complex refractive index and plug that into the exponent of the phase factor and saying the exponent will be real and decaying so is dissipative, but this still does not give a good physical picture of why "90 degree phase shift" comes with "dissipation".

Can someone give me an intuitive understanding of this? Thanks.

Comment: Although the post [Significance of the complex component in the under-damped harmonic motion equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/438621/significance-of-the-complex-component-in-the-underdamped-harmonic-motion-equatio) has been closed is it any use to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the motion in one dimension, the rate of doing work by a force $f$ acting on a body moving with velocity $v$ is $fv$.

Suppose a body is undergoing simple harmonic motion with position $x = x_0 \cos (\omega t)$. Its velocity is $\dot{x} = -\omega x_0 \sin(\omega t)$. The force producing this motion is $f = ma = -\omega^2 x_0 \cos(\omega t)$. The amount of work done on the body, per cycle, by this force is
$$
W = \int_0^T f v dt = \int_0^T -\omega^3 x_0^2 \cos(\omega t)  \sin(\omega t) dt = 0
$$
where $T$ is the period. The zero result is to be expected since for this situation the body is neither gaining nor losing energy on average during in each cycle.

Now let's suppose the motion remains simple harmonic to good approximation, but there is a further force acting and it is out of phase with the position. This further force has the time dependence
$$f_{90} = \gamma \sin(\omega t) .
$$
The notation here acts as a reminder that this force is 90$^\circ$ out of phase with the position. It could be a force proportional to speed, for example. The amount of work done by this force, per cycle, is
$$
W = \int_0^T f_{90} v dt = \int_0^T -\gamma \omega x_0 \cos^2(\omega t) dt = 
-\gamma \omega x_0 T/2.
$$
So that is the answer to the question. The message is that for a general time-dependence of the force applied to an oscillating body, the part that is in step with the position does no work on average per cycle, and the part that is in step with the velocity does net work in each cycle.

Comment: Thanks professor! This is very well-explained and helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The 90-degree phase lag only happens at the resonance frequency for this model. It is not general for all driving frequencies. See the Fig. 10 here: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waveshtml/node13.html

So 90-degrees phase lag represents the $\textit{least}$ dissipative situation.

Also, this model is also not general. This model is common because we can solve it exactly analytically, and it approximates many situations. Once you deviate from a Hookian spring term and linear in velocity damping term, the solutions will be different.